# Side Loading Features into ol.source.XYZ

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

Is there a way when using the `ol.source.XYZ` to sideload features?

The use case would be a map and a search feature external to OpenLayers which when a result is selected (maybe in an area not yet loaded by the XYZ source loader) it can push a GeoJSON feature into the same layer.

Comment: I'm currently using a ol.layer.VectorTile;

```
new ol.layer.VectorTile({
        projection: projection,
        renderMode: 'vector',
        source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
          projection: projection,
          format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
          url: this.state.getGeoJsonUrl(),
          tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({
            extent: extent
          })
        }),
        style: this._styler.bind(this)
      });
```

So far from research I think I need to use ol.source.Vector with a custom loader instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can save references to your features in your javascript. Use this reference, maybe an Array, to interact with your DOM and creating inputs, divs or whatever you want to create using your feature properties. You can construct a searchbox to search these DOM elements, and do what you want in the map.

Comment: Thanks but the issue's actually retrieving the data out of OpenLayers.

Comment: what information do you want to extract from Openlayers?

Comment: A feature by it's ID. e.g ol.source.Vector's getFeatureById() but then adding features in GeoJSON format too.